# Is the small number cache defined in Python specification or is it an implementation detail?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Python seems to have a so called "small number cache" for numbers in the range -5 to 256. We can demonstrate that with the following program:

```
for i in range(-7, 258):
    if id(i) == id(i + 0):
        print(i, "is cached")
    else:
        print(i, "is not cached")
```

The output is

```
-7 is not cached
-6 is not cached
-5 is cached
-4 is cached
[...]
255 is cached
256 is cached
257 is not cached
```

I wonder whether that's defined in the Python specification or it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I voted to re-open because I think this will make a good dupe target on it's own in the future.

Comment: Might be good to include the (abbreviated) output, so we don't all have to run it ourselves. Btw `--i` also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an implementation detail: [chapter 3.1 of the Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) (all versions, from 2.7 through 3.9) says:

> for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value

and

> E.g., after `a = 1; b = 1`, `a` and `b` may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, **depending on the implementation**

(emphasis mine)

The [Python/C API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) also mentions it

> **The current implementation** keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256,

(emphasis mine) which is also quite clear that this might change in the future.